# vs 2013 c# save bitmap from direct stream

Tags: c#, kinect

```
void CaptureTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureTimer.Stop();
        Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
        Graphics gr1 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = gr1.GetHdc();
        IntPtr dc2 = NativeMethods.GetWindowDC(NativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow());
        NativeMethods.BitBlt(dc1, (int)20, (int)20, (int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight, dc2, 20, 20, 13369376);
        gr1.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        bitmapImage.Save(string.Format(".\\Captures\\Capture{0}.jpg", rnd.Next().ToString()), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        PlaySoundOnButton(ButtonTypes.CaptureBtn);
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
```

[crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7gmr.png)

that is part of the code that crashing the program .
or do i need to put the whole code ?
i'm sorry troubling you guys this hour .

Comment: That's not an error message.  Please put the code and the actual error message _in your question_.

Comment: It's much more useful if you copy and paste code rather than posting screen shots.

Comment: exception is a complex object, it may have an inner exception. On your screenshot there is an action link "Copy exception details to clipboard". Sometimes this information is very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible issues with your code:

a) You are not calling `Dispose` on some of your variables (or using `using` so that it is done for you). [bitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx) is one such example.

b) Your use of ".\Captures..." for saving files is problematic, since it is dependent on the [Current Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx). This could be a problem if the current directory changes to, for example, the Windows directory (where your program likely lacks permission to write files).

c) `Random rnd = new Random();` may result in the same filename being generated more than once (especially if called in quick succession) - which may mean old screenshots are lost / overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        string path = @"f:\temp\MyTest.tif";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)workspace.ActualWidth,
            (int)workspace.ActualHeight, 1 / 96, 1 / 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(workspace);
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        encoder.Save(fs);
        fs.Close();
    }
```

thanks for advising me @mjwills @SLaks @juharr @Aleks Andreev